# Keeping header "on top" in landscape mode

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, landscape

When using `pdflscape` and `fancyhdr`, the headers also get rotated. Whilst it's a normal behaviour in most cases (especially when the document has to be printed), I am dealing with a report which will **never** be printed, so this default behaviour is more annoying.

Here is a MWE of a document dealing with portrait and landscape pages:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{32pt}

\lhead{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{tt}\\Foo}
\rhead{\includegraphics[scale=.5]{tt}\\\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\fancypagestyle{customlandscape}{%
\fancyhf{}
\newgeometry{left=1cm, right=1cm, bottom=1cm, top=1cm}
% ??
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]
\newpage

\pagestyle{customlandscape}
\begin{landscape}
    Here is the landscaped content, the header of this page should look like the rest...
\end{landscape}


\newpage
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Note : you will have to provide 2 images called `tt` for it to compile, sorry for that. So, if we look a bit closer, the header of the portrait pages look like this :

[image: portrait page]

How can I manage for my landscape pages to look like this ? :
[image: landscape page]

Currently, by compiling my MWE, you'll notice that the header is on the right on the landscape page.

PS : There is another problem in this MWE, after switching back to portrait, it seems I'm not able to restore the default pagestyle (with the images in the header).

Comment: Instead of pdflscape you could use graphicx \rotatebox{90}{\begin{minipage}{\textheight}...\end{minipage}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without lscap package you change page format to landscape by

```
\newpage

\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
```

here the problem was to adapt the headwidth length

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{32pt}

\lhead{tt\\Foo}
\rhead{vv\\\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\newlength{\mtL}
\setlength{\mtL}{.8\paperheight}% the next hsize
\addtolength\mtL{-\headwidth}
\newpage
\addtolength\headwidth{\mtL}

%landsape
\pdfpageheight=\paperwidth
\pdfpagewidth=\paperheight
\paperwidth=\pdfpagewidth
\paperheight=\pdfpageheight

%text width and height
\begingroup 
\vsize=.8\pdfpageheight % do what you like
\hsize=.8\pdfpagewidth  % do what you like
\textwidth=\hsize
\textheight=\vsize
% you can specify the margins

\lipsum[1]

\endgroup
\newpage

\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth


\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

edit for more pagestyle{fancy}

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[left=2cm, right=2cm, bottom=2cm, top=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\headheight}{32pt}

\lhead{tt\\Foo}
\rhead{vv\\\thepage}
\cfoot{}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-10]

\newlength{\mtL}
\setlength{\mtL}{.8\paperheight}% the next hsize
\addtolength\mtL{-\headwidth}
\newpage
\addtolength\headwidth{\mtL}

%landscape
\pdfpageheight=\paperwidth
\pdfpagewidth=\paperheight
\paperwidth=\pdfpagewidth
\paperheight=\pdfpageheight

%text width and height
\begingroup 
\vsize=.8\pdfpageheight % do what you like
\hsize=.8\pdfpagewidth  % do what you like
\textwidth=\hsize
\textheight=\vsize
% you can specify the margins

\lipsum[1-10]

\endgroup
\newpage
\addtolength\headwidth{-1\mtL}
\paperwidth=\pdfpageheight
\paperheight=\pdfpagewidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth


\lipsum[1-20]

\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. The part which switches to landscape works perfectly, I managed to do it fit my needs. Yet, I am having a problem when switching back to portrait. Using your code, it seems the right part of the header is out of the page on portrait mode, as if a length was not reseted. Any input ?

Comment: what do you mean by after landsacap. After landsacape is just befor \pagestyle plain

Comment: Well imagine the following document : page in portrait > page in portrait > page in landscape > page in landscape > page in portrait. The latter is not properly rendered, as mentioned above.

Comment: I edited my ansower

Comment: Footer option seems like broken with this approach. Could you please clarify?

Answer (score 0):

This code works pretty good, but if the change from portrait to landscape is done, the footer gets lost on the first landscape page but appears on the following pages again.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. How is this an answer?