# How can I rotate some pages keeping the same header/footer sequence as the other pages?

Tags: tables, graphics, header-footer, rotating

<sub>*Original text*</sub>

Estoy intentando rotar hojas específicas de cuadros o imágenes un poco anchas para lo cual algunas hojas deben estar rotadas para facilitar la lectura.

<sub>*Translation by Gonzalo Medina*</sub>

In order to facilitate reading, I'm trying to rotate some specific pages containing tables or images which are wider than `\textwidth`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: English please.

Comment: @Jesse your wish is my command ;-)

Comment: Hola, Arnold. Traduje la pregunta al inglés para que todos puedan entenderla. Hi, Arnold. I translated your question to English so everyone can understand it.

Comment: Prefiero el español.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina  You are incredible, Sir.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández En este sitio el idioma a usar es el inglés; pero, por supuesto, si quiere puedo deshacer mi edición y volver al texto original en español. Sin embargo, la pregunta solo será leida por los usuarios que entiended español (muy pocos, comparados con los que entienden el inglés). Por favor indíqueme si quiere que vuelva al texto original en español.

Comment: related http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226324/keeping-header-on-top-in-landscape-mode

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Gracias por tu tiempo. Si alguien traduce desinteresadamente no me parece malo. Si puede estar en español y la duplicas al inglés sería excelente.

Comment: De acuerdo. Ahora estoy con el celular. Cuando llegue a casa agrego el texto original.

Comment: @ArnoldFernández Hola. Ya he agregado el texto original (no en el título, pues quedarís muy largo). La pregunta ha side corrada como duplicado. Si la solución que aparece en el enlace a la otra pregunta no te sirve, no dudes en abrir una nueva pregunta, explicando qué es lo que necesitas y que la otra pregunta no resuelve.