# \newgeometry landscape only works once

Tags: geometry, landscape

I have a document in 'portrait' format, and would like to include short sections in 'landscape' format.

The geometry package works nicely, but only allows me to insert one such section. The second call to `\newgeometry` fails to orient the page to landscape format. I have tried `\savegeometry` and `\loadgeometry` to no avail.

Is there any way to use the geometry package for multiple 'landscape' sections? Is there an alternative?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\ifGm@preamble#1{\@firstofone}
\appto\restoregeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}
\apptocmd\newgeometry{%
  \pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
  \pdfpageheight=\paperheight}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\newgeometry{,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm,landscape}  
\section{One One}
\lipsum[1]

\restoregeometry
\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[6]

\newgeometry{,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm,landscape}
\section{Two One}
\lipsum[3-5]

\restoregeometry
\section{Two Two}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The modification disables the warning "landscape not allowed in newgeometry".  Obviously there is a reason for the warning, other than just being nasty.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440307/43317 helps.

Comment: Very helpful thanks, the typearea package discussed there is a good option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `pdflscape` package together with `\newgeomety`.

```
\usepackage[a4paper,hmargin=3cm,vmargin=5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdflscape,lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\begin{document}

\chapter{One}
\lipsum[1]

\newgeometry{,vmargin=3cm,hmargin=5cm} 
\begin{landscape}
 \section{One One}
\lipsum[1]
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry

\chapter{Two}
\lipsum[6]

\newgeometry{,vmargin=3cm,hmargin=5cm}
\begin{landscape}
\section{Two One}
\lipsum[3-5]
\end{landscape}
\restoregeometry
\section{Two Two}
\lipsum[6]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this works, this does not change the location of the page numbers

Comment: @Murmel - I take it you want to move and rotate the page number.  That is covered elsewhere.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278113/single-landscape-page-with-page-number-at-the-bottom

Comment: I will definitely have a look at it, but I only wanted to emphasize the difference between your solution and the MWE of @Alex Lehmann