# How to design 2 types of footer, like in this example?

Tags: header-footer

How are you all?
Here we go again, with our TeX adventures.

Problem is. Some pages of my document are A3 format because they are huge diagrams. The rest is A4 format. The footer set is in the A4 format, and the same footer gets displayed in the A3 format.

What I am trying to achieve is to have a longer line in the A3 footer, longer spacing, etc. That is, proportional to this A3 format. I believe I would have to "break" this footer in favor of another one, and the get the A4 footer to continue from the point where it was "broken", in the next A4 page. I also have attached a image with what I have now. Any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

[image: Example of that I have now and want to change]

The code I have for the standard A4 footer is:
(I am sorry if the MWE is too long, feel free to edit out unneeded parts)

```
\lfoot{\footnotesize \texttt{Structured Cabling} \textbullet ~Projeto}       
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}  % "Page 1 of 2"
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
```

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[ DIV=calc,%
                            paper=a4,%
                            fontsize=12pt,%
                            onecolumn]{scrartcl}                        % KOMA-article class

\usepackage{lipsum}         % Package to create dummy text
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}  % English language/hyphenation
\usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}  % Better typography
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm}                    % Math packages
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}                           % Enable pdflatex
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}           % Enabling colors by their 'svgnames'
\usepackage[hang, small,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption}    % Custom captions under/above floats
\usepackage{epstopdf}                       % Converts .eps to .pdf
\usepackage{subfig}                         % Subfigures
\usepackage{booktabs}       % Nicer tables
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{fix-cm}                                                 % Custom fontsizes
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ddmmyyyy]{datetime}
\addto\captionsenglish{%
    \renewcommand\tablename{Tabela}
    \renewcommand\figurename{Figura}
} 



%%% Custom sectioning (sectsty package)
\usepackage{sectsty}                                                    % Custom sectioning (see below)
\allsectionsfont{%                                                          % Change font of al section commands
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                                       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    }

\sectionfont{%                                                              % Change font of \section command
    \usefont{OT1}{phv}{b}{n}%                                       % bch-b-n: CharterBT-Bold font
    }



%%% Headers and footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                                               % Needed to define custom headers/footers
    \pagestyle{fancy}                                                       % Enabling the custom headers/footers
\usepackage{lastpage}   

% Header (empty)
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{}
% Footer (you may change this to your own needs)


\lfoot{\footnotesize \texttt{Cabeamento estruturado} \textbullet ~Projeto}


\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\footnotesize Página \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}    % "Page 1 of 2"
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}



%%% Creating an initial of the very first character of the content
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\initial}[1]{%
     \lettrine[lines=3,lhang=0.3,nindent=0em]{
                    \color{DarkBlue}
                    {\textsf{#1}}}{}}
```

And I think I need to show how I am turning the pages to A3/Landscape and back to A4/portrait.

```
%create landscape A3
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a3, paper=landscape, DIV=20}
\recalctypearea
%\subsection{Topologia}

\begin{figure}
    %   \centering
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth][c]{
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{topologia}
    }
    \caption{Visão da topologia - Formato A3}
    \label{fig1}
\end{figure}

% go back to A4/portrait
\clearpage
\KOMAoptions{paper=a4, paper=portrait, DIV=15}
\recalctypearea
```

Comment: Please provide a MWE so that we know which packages you use. Also, this is likely a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226324/keeping-header-on-top-in-landscape-mode

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yeah, I pasted the MWE. I see that it may have duplicates, okay. I didn't try header in the search. I just didn't found any footer example on this. Thank you for your help.